# Generating random vertices that don't repeat

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph

I have the following code that is generating a random number of tuples in order to create a connected undirect weighted graph.

```
for i in xrange(0,10):
     for j in xrange(0, (int)(10*random.random())):
          b = (int)(10*random.random())
          j = [(i,b)]
          print(j)
```

When I run this code I am able to randomly generate random vertices (x,y), however I am running into an issue in that my b variable has the possibility of repeating twice. For example I may get (6,3) followed by (6,3) which when I add weights would ruin the graphs I'm trying to create. Also I am sometimes running into issues where I might get (2,4) and then later get (4,2) which again ruins the graphs that I'm trying to create.

Does anyone know how I can keep vertices from repeating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
>>> lst1 = random.sample(range(20), 10)
>>> lst2 = random.sample(range(20), 10)
>>> zip(lst1, lst2)
[(19, 5), (5, 11), (9, 19), (0, 9), (4, 6), (12, 0), (7, 12), (16, 1), (10, 7), (15, 16)]
```

You can change the `list` generated by `range(20)` to suit your set of vertices.

Don't generate a new vertex inside the `for` loop, since it may generate the same one again. (don't pick randomly off of the `random.sample` lists) Just generate them once and `zip` them together.

Since you want to remove duplicates of type `(x, y)` and `(y, x)`. You can do something like the following. (or the simple `in` method works too)

```
>>> r = [(19, 5), (5, 11), (5, 19)]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> m = map(set, r)
>>> m
[set([19, 5]), set([11, 5]), set([19, 5])]
>>> sorted(m, key=lambda x: sum(x))
[set([11, 5]), set([19, 5]), set([19, 5])]
>>> [tuple(k) for k, v in groupby(sorted(m, key = lambda x: sum(x)))]
[(11, 5), (19, 5)]
```

Comment: This works perfect! If I wanted to add weights to the graphs that are at most 10 would I just do lst3 = random.sample(range(10), 10) and then add that to my zip?

Comment: Yes. If you want to generate a tuple of the form `((x, y), cost)`, that should work fine.